# Is there any way to send the diagnostic response(UDS) from one bus to another bus using capl?

Tags: capl, canoe

I have a situation 
When i am making the diagnostic request from canoe. ECU responding with the response(Request correctly received but response pending). After some time i am getting positive response from the ECU. I just want to send the positive response from the current bus to another bus by cutting out the response pending response. How can i do that using capl?

Comment: What kind of busses are they?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a gateway. I.e. a node connected to the two busses. For one bus, the node acts as a tester (sending requests and listens to responses) for the other bus, the node acts as ECU.

You listen for responses in one bus by using `on diagResponse CAN1.*` and if it is a positive response you send it to the other bus by using `diagSendResponse CAN2.<responseMessage>`

Replace CAN1 and CAN2 with the actual bus names.

Also check the Applications Note called *Diagnostics Gateway* or something like that coming with CANoe.

Another option is to do this not on the application layer but on the data layer. I.e. not by listening and forwarding diagnostics messages but by listening to the transported data. 
What makes more sense for you depends on your exact setup; but details are unknown.

Comment: @Uma - Consider accepting this answer if your question is resolved.